# Add buttons to grid with either icons or text in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have a EXGrid in a form and want to add button to a cell that either say "Edit" and "Remove", or Have icons for the two. Here is the code I have so far.

```
 With grdGrade
    .BeginUpdate
        '.DataSource = objCo.DAL.Connection.Execute(sql)
        .DefaultItemHeight = 21

        .TreeColumnIndex = -1
        .MarkSearchColumn = False
        .FullRowSelect = exItemSel
        .DrawGridLines = exAllLines
        .SortOnClick = exNoSort
        .BackColorHeader = grdGrade.BackColor
        .Appearance = Flat
        .BackColorAlternate = Me.BackColor
        .SelBackColor = RGB(224, 224, 224)
        .SelForeColor = vbBlack
        .UseTabKey = True
        .Font = Me.Font

    .EndUpdate
End With

Set col = grdGrade.Columns.Add("Actions")
col.AllowDragging = False
col.Width = grdGrade.Width * 0.05
col.Editor.AddButton "Edit", , 0
col.Editor.AddButton "Remove", , 0
col.Editor.EditType = ButtonType
```

Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Just to add. Right now the buttons are there they are just blank.

Comment: I finally got it. When loading the grid I used: 
    Me.grdGrade.Items.CellValue(h, "Actions") = "    Edit    "
    Me.grdGrade.Items.CellHasButton(h, "Actions") = True
    s = Me.grdGrade.Items.SplitCell(h, "Actions")
    Me.grdGrade.Items.CellValue(0, s) = "  Remove  "
    Me.grdGrade.Items.CellHasButton(0, s) = True

and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. When loading the grid I used:

```
Me.grdGrade.Items.CellValue(h, "Actions") = " Edit " 
Me.grdGrade.Items.CellHasButton(h, "Actions") = True 
s = Me.grdGrade.Items.SplitCell(h, "Actions") 
Me.grdGrade.Items.CellValue(0, s) = " Remove " 
Me.grdGrade.Items.CellHasButton(0, s) = True
```

and it works like a charm